# Cyborg R.A.T. 9 Mouse keeps freezing

Tags: mouse, freeze

I just got myself a new Cyborg R.A.T 9 mouse. The problem is that the mouse keeps freezing. Well not really. I can still move the cursor around but I'm not able to open/close anything. The clicks won't be recognized. As soon as I plug the USB to the laptop, the Touchpad won't work either. It only works correctly when I unplug the USB again.

What can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to AskUbuntu.

I have found a solution that may be useful to you.

On the terminal, type `sudo su`.

Next, create a new configuration file, by typing 
`gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-cyborgrat9.conf`

Copy and paste this code into the config file.

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "R.A.T."
        MatchProduct "R.A.T.7|R.A.T.9"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Option "Buttons” “17"
        Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 0 0 8 9 7 6 12 0 0 0 16 17"
        Option "AutoReleaseButtons" "13 14 15"
        Option "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection
```

Lastly, reboot your computer.

Comment: @MrArrow If it works, mind if you also upvote? :) Happy that it is working for you and the rest of the community.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old one, but I still use my rat mice. Ubuntu has switched things up. owl's answer is no longer correct for Ubuntu 14.04/16.04.

The files should now be placed in: `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` (ubuntu no longer uses /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/)

Here's the files have I have for my mice:

cat `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/rat7mouse.conf`

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Mouse Remap"
    MatchProduct "Saitek Cyborg R.A.T.7 Mouse"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

cat `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/rat9mouse.conf`

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Mouse Remap"
    MatchProduct "Saitek Cyborg R.A.T.9 Wireless Mouse"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

Don't forget to restart the PC for the changes to kick in.

An alternative solution is to enable the kernel driver for it:
https://github.com/rkruk/R.A.T.-Cyborg-Mouse-on-Linux

If you are having issues with the double-click when single-clicking the wheel, check this out: http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php/753083-Fixing-Mad-Catz-M-M-O-7-double-click-issue-DIY