# Mouse click working intermittently

Tags: mouse, window

I just installed ubuntu for the first time, I was anxiously waiting to start programming and what do I find? The mouse doesn't work correctly... It seems like the clicking falls through the layers of application's windows, I notice trying to drag some window and selecting some text on a browser behind it... I search around and everyone is telling to call compiz --replace & every time it happens, and it is like once every minute... that is really disappointing... I am doing some updates to see if it fixes it, but can someone point me in the right direction here? Thanks!

I tried this: [Ubuntu 14.04 mouse and window focus issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451080/ubuntu-14-04-mouse-and-window-focus-issues?newreg=cda3f41d3cb947d5876e4e569dd90767)

But it stopped working after a while

My mouse is a Cyborg Rat 9

Comment: What mouse are you using ? 
Are you using 16.04?

Comment: My mouse is Cyborg Rat 9

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/416640/cyborg-r-a-t-9-mouse-keeps-freezing

Comment: Someone else had the same issue and the settings file to correct it is larger than the one you tried for a similar mouse. I hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: It worked! Would you mind posting and answer so I can close this post? You may just post a link the the other post :)